# How can I create a tar on bastion?

Tags: ansible

The following code doesn't create my tar :

```yaml
- name: Create my pza_project tar   
  archive:
      path: "/home/ansible/delivery/qpm"
      dest: "/tmp/pza_project.tar"
      format: "tar"
```

The log is :

> TASK [Create my pza_project tar] **************************
> task path: /home/ansible/delivery/pza_playbook.yml:141
> ok: [X.XXX.XXX.XX] => {"archived": [], "arcroot": "/home/ansible/delivery/qpm/", "changed": false, "dest": "/tmp/pza_project.tar", "expanded_exclude_paths": [], "expanded_paths": ["/home/ansible/delivery/qpm/"], "missing": ["/home/ansible/delivery/qpm/"], "state": "absent"}

Whereas this one creates my tar :

```yaml
- name: Create my pza_project tar
  archive:
    path: "/home/ansible/delivery/qpm"
    dest: "/tmp/pza_project.tar"
    format: "tar"   
  delegate_to: localhost   
  become: false
```

"qpm" is a directory present in my Gitlab project.
During the pipeline execution, I can read in log that all the files and directories of "qpm" are copied on the bastion :

```
qpm/my_fileA.txt File copied 
qpm/my_fileB.txt File copied 
...
```

The bastion is :

> /home/ansible/delivery

So my qpm directory exists on the bastion, doesn't it ?

By default, the "path" field of archive task must be a path of my server (configured in my inventory) but not of the bastion ?

Thus, to make my tar with the bastion's files, I have to use

```
delegate_to: localhost
```

Is it correct ?
Does localhost represent the bastion ?

Comment: `Could you explain why the following code doesn't create my tar?` <= because the directory your are trying to tar does not exist on the target (as explained in the error msg `..."missing": ["/home/ansible/delivery/qpm/"], "state": "absent"...`) but obviously does on the host you are delegating to (i.e. the controller `localhost` in that specific case)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've modified my question in order to be clearer.

Comment: [_The source and archive are on the remote host, and the archive is not copied to the local host._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html) > So what you should do is keep your delegation to localhost, and then, copy the the resulting tar on your node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `/home/ansible/delivery/qpm/` is missing.

`delegate_to` is an option to any task, not a mandatory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've modified my question in order to be clearer.